# Mapping an iterable 1-to-n in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, iterable

What I am trying to do is use the `Iterable.map` but instead of transforming every one value to one new value, I want to transform one value to multiple new values.

For example:

```
val myList = listOf("test", "123", "another.test", "test2")
val result = myList.map {
    if(it.contains(".")) {
        return@map it.split(".")
    } else {
        return@map it
    }
}
//desired output: ["test", "123", "another", "test", "test2"]
```

This code would result in a List which contains both strings and lists of strings (type `Any`).

How could I most elegantly implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick way to do this is using `flatMap`.

```
val output = myList.flatMap { if(it.contains(".")) it.split(".") else listOf(it) }
```

The `flatMap` method transforms the each element using given function and then flatten the result to a single list.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html